# Rss feed iotdhandler code generating error

Tags: android

I am trying create RSS feed app for site and referring headfirst android development book (chapter 3) in which layout of application is running fine but when I try to add `IodtHandler` code in my project and trying to perform `IotdHandler handler=new IotdHandler();` it generates the below error

> IodtHandler cannot be resolved a type

It is not possible to move forward before completing this code. Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have forgot the import statement.
In eclipse, press *Ctrl+Shift+O* to automatically arrange your imports.